# dudas mostrar productos

Tags: java

Necesito desarrollar un programa que me permita ingresar productos y mostrarlos ojalá filtrándolos según alguna preferencia. Tengo tres objetos; ingresar productos, mostrar productos y productos. La idea es que la clase productos dispare el programa, y las otras tengan el código para ingresar y mostrar productos, pero tengo problemas con las relaciones (pasar atributos entre clases) entre los objetos. Alguien me puede ayudar?

CLASE INGRESAR PRODUCTOS:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IngresarProductos {
    private Scanner teclado;
    private String[] categoria;
    private String[] categoriaMarca;
    public void cargar() {
        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        categoria = new String[4];
        categoriaMarca = new String[4];
        System.out.println("Carga de productos");
        for(int f=0; f<categoria.length;f++) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese la categoría del producto ");
            categoria[f] = teclado.next();
            System.out.print("Ingrese la marca del producto ");
            categoriaMarca[f] = teclado.next();  
        }
    }
}
```

CLASE MOSTRAR PRODUCTOS:

```
    public class MostrarProductos {
        public void imprimir() {
            IngresarProductos nuevo = new IngresarProductos;
            for (int f = 0; f<categoria.length;f++) {
                System.out.println(categoria[f] + " - " + categoriaMarca[f]);               
            }
        }
    }
```

CLASE PRODUCTOS:

```
public class Productos {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        IngresarProductos nuevo = new IngresarProductos();
        nuevo.cargar();
        System.out.println("Lista de productos ingresados: ");
        nuevo.imprimir();
    }
}
```

Comment: no está claro lo que quieres preguntar, añade detalles que ayuden a la pregunta

Comment: la primera pregunta es.. porque hay 3 clases y no son el mismo programa?

Comment: Como es programación orientada a objetos, decidí estructurar el código de tal manera que si quisiera agregar otras funcionalidades (por ejemplo ingresar sub-categorías de productos) o agregar o modificar ligeramente algunas funcionalidades, pudiese hacerlo más fácilmente modificando cada clase de objeto.